# Lagrangians : Why is $\frac{\partial (x^2)}{\partial \dot x} = 0$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In working with Lagrangians, when we write $L = T - V$. Then we use an equation of this sort (considering only one dimension for simplicity):

$$ \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\right) = \dfrac{\partial L}{\partial x} $$

Now, for simplicity, write the Lagrangian of a mass $m$ attached to a spring of constant $k$. So, we have: $L = 0.5m{\dot x}^2 - 0.5kx^2$.

We then write $\dfrac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} = m\dot x$, taking $\dfrac{\partial (0.5kx^2)}{\partial \dot x} = 0$.

My question is, how is that valid? Isn't it like saying that $x$ and $\dot x$ are independent? But that doesn't make sense intuitively. Velocity can be thought of as a function of the displacement. So, what's going on?

Comment: For situation 1, $\theta$ depends on $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So in turn can't we say $y$ depends upon $x$ and $\theta$? And anyhow, what should we equate $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ to? Zero? Or, $\tan \theta$?

Comment: Zero. For instance let $f(x,y) = x+ y$. Then $f_{x}(x,y) = 1$. Also the point is that if you (implicitly) differentiate $x\tan\theta$, then you have to use the product and chain rules since $\theta$ depends on $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a confusing notation. In one dimension the Lagrangian is a function $L:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ (I'm assuming no explicit time dependency for brevity), say $L=L(y,z)$ (or maybe you would only call $L(y,z)\big|_{(y,z)=(x,\dot{x})}$ the Lagrangian, but whatever). Then what $\displaystyle\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{x}}$ really means is $\displaystyle \frac{\partial L\,(y,z)}{\partial z}\big|_{(y,z)=(x,\dot{x})}\,.$ So you see we aren't in any way treating $x,\dot{x}$ as independent.

Comment: How aren't we? We're taking $\dfrac{\partial y^2 }{\partial z} = 0$, which means we're treating $y$ and $z$ as independent.  And $y$ and $z$ stand for $x$ and $\dot x$.

Comment: @ParthThakkar Actually $y,z$ are independent, but they do not stand for $x,\dot{x}\,,$ they can both be any real number. We just happen to evaluate $L(y,z)$ at points where $(y,z)=(x,\dot{x})\,,$ but the differentiation I have done is perfectly well-defined; we can change $z$ however we want while keeping $y$ fixed. First we differentiate $L(y,z)$ with respect to $z$ and then we evaluate this derivative at $(y,z)=(x,\dot{x})\,.$

Comment: Alright. If looked at it that way, it seems fine. Thanks!

Comment: I would have suggested reading up on calculus of variations and functional derivatives